# Java nested genericsType

Tags: java, generics

I got an interesting issue. Consider the following code:

```
public class GenericsTest
{
    // An interface with a generic type.
    public interface IObject<K>{}

    // An class with a generic type
    public static class ObjectA<K>
    {
        // An inner class without generic type, but implementing the interface with generic Type
        // When adding a genericType to this class, it will popup the warning: 'hiding'
        public class ObjectB implements IObject<K>
        {

        }

        // A getter with the interface as return Type
        public IObject<K> getObjectB()
        {
            return new ObjectB();
        }
    }

    public ObjectA<String> objectA = new ObjectA<String>();

    // This field is yelling for an genericType, though it can't get one because the class doesn't support a generic argument.
    public ObjectB genericObject = (ObjectB)objectA.getObjectB();
}
```

So the issue is that my IDE is complaining about a missing genericType of the `genericObject` field, and that I should add a `SupressWarning` annotation to the method. (luckily not code breaking, though still pretty annoying).

I could add a generic type to the inner class, though than it would 'hide' a generic argument, meaning I would need to add a `SupressWarning` annotation there.

A second fix would be to use a second generic type like *<S extends K>*. In which case I don't need a `SupressWarning` annotation at the class. Though when I try to use the getter, my IDE is complaining:

```
The member type GenericsTest.ObjectA.ObjectB<String> must be qualified with a parameterized type, since it is not static.
```

So basically I can't use the getter, unless I add an argument of the genericType to the method.

My question is, what is the cleanest way to solve this problem without changing the inner class to a nested class?

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't complain about it if I do `public ObjectA.ObjectB genericObject = (ObjectA.ObjectB)objectA.getObjectB();`

Comment: NetBeans IDE says "Cannot find ObjectB".  Do you have its definition somewhere?

Comment: @.cricket_007 I use eclipse, and it is defenitly complaining about the situations I described above. Though @.Andrew Williamson had brought the solution, which is almost exactly the same as yours. @.markspace I dont follow your question totaly, since I can refer to ObjectB perfectly, (it needs to import it though(which isn't visible here), but other than that, it doesnt complain about anything, except the generics thingy).  Anyway thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a short example that compiles with no issues:

```
public class Test
{
    interface K<T> { }

    static class A<T>
    {
        class B implements K<T> { }

        public K<T> getK() { return new B(); }
    }

    A<String> a = new A<String>();
    A<String>.B b = (A<String>.B) a.getK();
}
```

Notice the last line:

```
A<String>.B b = (A<String>.B) a.getK();
```

To be honest, I'm not sure how the example you've given even compiles as far as it does - the class 'ObjectB' is not visible from the main 'GenericsTest' scope, it needs to be prefixed with its' parent class.

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for. pretty obvious if I look at it, I wonder why I didnt think of that earlier :P. Thank you! About the visibility of ObjectB, I know it isnt visible in the example I posted, but eclipse automatically imported the subclass (like it was a nested class). so thats why I could use it in this way. It also explains why it would complain about the generics.

Comment: Yeah, Eclipse does some pretty non-standard things when compiling. It sometimes ruins the "write once, run anywhere" ideology of Java.